# Passing std::filesystem::path in class constructor by / not default

Tags: c++, windows, path, filesystems, visual-studio-2019

I'm working on a class, that has a constructor parameterized with a type of `std::filesystem::path&`. The parameter has a default value. So

```
class Builder {
public:
      Builder(const std::filesystem::path& in = "res/My.json");
}
```

Then I instantiate an object in `main()` function and code works like it was meant

```
int main() {
Builder* b = new Builder();
delete b;
return 0;
}
```

But if I put and use any argument out of range of

```
std::filesystem::path = "res/My.json" 
std::string arg = "res/My.json" 
std::string_view arg = "res/My.json" 
const char* arg = "res/My.json"
```

within `main()`, it gives out an error and the file cannot be read from `"res/My.json"`. The direction of slashes `/` or `\\` does not influence

```
int main() {
std::string arg = "res/My.json";
Builder* b = new Builder(arg);
delete b;
return 0;
}
```

However, if I put a full path in the argument like `... = "C:/Folder/files/res/My.json";` or `"../files/rsc/My.json"` with any type (...) like indicated above, the application executes

```
int main() {
std::string arg = "C:/Folder/files/res/My.json";
Builder* b = new Builder(arg);
delete b;
return 0;
}
```

What is an implicit error during this code execution? How to make parameters pathes equal and cross-platform?

Comment: Off topic: `void main` is invalid C++. The `main` must have `int` as return value.

Comment: [OT]: `new` is unneeded, `Builder b(arg);` is enough. (and avoid memory leak).

Comment: Check your working directory.

Comment: Without full path name, it mean that a $PWD = present working directory is added on top of the relative path. Therefore, if you are not working in the directory c:\folder\files, the relative path together with $PWD won't give a correct path.

Comment: @ytlu this did not help, unfortunately

Comment: Could you display the specific content of `Builder` and the error message given by `main()`? In Windows, `../` represents the upper level directory represented by the current path. I think this path `../files/rsc/My.json` may be the only path in your disk.

Comment: @Barrnet Chou The code compiles. So now if I use the path set by default in the header, the code compiles, but the json file would not open. However, if I set the same path inside the main() function, the code works then. Strange.

Comment: I suggest that you could submit this question to [Microsoft Develper Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).